# Excell cell calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel

Can I set a cell in excel to have a formula in it, that when I write a figure into that cell it automatically applies the formula to it and presnts the calculated figure instead.

i.e; if in cell A1 I want to write a number, say 10; but I want the cell (A1) to calculate 125% of 10. Result being 12.5; shown in cell A1

Comment: You will want vba in a worksheet_change event.

Comment: Never done this before. In Microsoft Visual Basic Developer Tab I assume. What would I need to do once there?

Comment: Just google for "worksheet_change example"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following worksheet event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rINT As Range
    Set rINT = Intersect(Target, Range("A1"))
    If rINT Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("A1").Value = 1.25 * Range("A1").Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

**EDIT#1:**

To do this for a block of cells, say **A1** through **A10**, replace the previous macro with:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rINT As Range, r As Range
    Set rINT = Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10"))
    If rINT Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each r In rINT
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            r.Value = 1.25 * r.Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for all comments. Managed to get it to work with one I found on google search. Last comment seems a lot cleaner than that I found, and I used this also. All good. One thing though. If I want this to be done to a list of figurers in let's say A1:A10,; do I have to set up repeatedly in new windows, or can I change the range to A1:A10?

Comment: @john  **no** .................I will update the post with a replacement macro...................

Comment: Thank you so much. Thought I could use excel. Whole new world of possibilities opening up.

Comment: @john  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @john Since it worked brilliantly, please mark it as answer.